# Find the Theta class for the recursion $T(n)=T(5n/6)+T(n/6)+n$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

$$T(n) = T\left(5n\over6\right) + T\left(n\over6\right) + n$$ is not in the proper form for the Master theorem so I can't really apply it.
I thought of doing something like that:
$$T(n) = 2T\left(5n\over6\right)+n $$ for big O
and $$T(n) = 2T\left(n\over6\right)+n $$ for big omega.

but I do not succeed, someone can help me?
Thanks you!

Comment: AFAIK there is a generalization of the "Master Theorem" which would tell you that $T$ (once properly defined, i.e. you have to continue it to the positive real numbers for instance by setting $T(x)\overset{\text{Def.}}=T(\lceil x\rceil)$ and technically you should also deal with the initial conditions, but most computer science classes brush over this) is in the class $\Theta(n^k\ln(n))$.

Comment: above: $k=1$; I mean [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master-Theorem#Allgemeinere_Form) (I didn't find an english version, sorry); however, they also don't have a proof...... . This Theorem works, but it is total overkill: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I got instructions to solve this with the help of the recursion tree method.

Comment: Have you tried drawing out the first couple of levels of the recursion tree and seeing how much work is done per level?

Comment: Of course, I tried 5/6+1/6=1, therefore, we have n work on each instruction but the tree is asymmetrical, the right side is bigger than the left side of the tree. size of the right $logn$ base 6/5 and left side $logn$ base 6.